# Find $\det (A+B)$ where $\det A = 0$, and $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of order $n$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Well considering two $n\times n$ matrices what is the general formula of
$\det(A+xB)$ ?
What can be said about $\det(A+B)$?

By the way $A$ is not invertible. $B$ as well.
I tried expansion but there is too much calculus.

Help me to find an easier way and a concrete general formula.

Comment: If $f(x)=\det(A+xB)$ then of course $\det(A+B)=f(1)$. For a formula, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189714/polynomial-form-of-detaxb), for example.

Comment: Firstt, compute $A+xB$. Then, compute the determinant of the result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $\det(A+xB)$ have a nice form for $3 \times 3$ matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132881/does-detaxb-have-a-nice-form-for-3-times-3-matrices)

Comment: @DietrichBurde not a duplicate in my opinion, because those links are for 2x2 and 3x3 matrices

Comment: @supinf This is what the OP can expect, i.e., a formula for $n=2,3$. For $n\ge 4$ these formulas are too difficult to describe. So it is a duplicate in my opinion. Of course, you (and the OP) may prefer the answer below, that one cannot say anything. Literally. It depends on the interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> What can be said about det(A+B)?

From just knowing that $A$ and $B$ are non-invertible, **nothing**. Literally.

For every $d\in\mathbb R$ and every $n\geq 2$, there exists a pair of non-invertible matrices such that $\det(A+B)=d$.

For example, take the matrix $E$ the matrix with all elements except $E_{1,1}$ set to zero, with $E_{1,1}=1$, in other words $$E=\begin{bmatrix}1 &0& \dots&0\\0 & 0 & \dots &0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&\dots&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Now take $A=d\cdot E$ and $B=I-E$. Then, $A$ is non-invertible, $B$ is non-invertible, and $\det(A+B)=d$.